# Migrate vue chrome extension from manifest 2 to 3

Tags: vue.js, webpack, google-chrome-extension

How are you? I'm trying to migrate the version of extension from 2 to 3. For now, I want to get the result of build with version 3 so that I can upload it to the store. This is main reason why I'm migrating the extension.

It would be greatly appreciated if anyone give detailed solutions to be matched with my project? Looking forward to hearing from you.

This is origin manifest file. If you need more detail, I will provide.

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "version": "0.9.9",
  "name": "AAAAAA",
  "description": "BBBBBB",
  "homepage_url": "https://AAA.co",
  "permissions": [
    "notifications",
    "storage",
    "activeTab",
    "unlimitedStorage"
  ],
  "icons": {
    "16": "icons/icon.png",
    "48": "icons/icon.png",
    "128": "icons/icon.png",
    "256": "icons/icon.png",
    "512": "icons/icon.png",
    "1024": "icons/icon.png"
  },
  "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "js/background.js"
    ],
    "persistent": true
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "file://*/*",
        "http://*/*",
        "https://*/*"
      ],
      "js": [
        "js/content-script.js"
      ],
      "run_at": "document_start",
      "all_frames": false
    }
  ],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_icon": {
      "16": "icons/icon.png",
      "48": "icons/icon.png",
      "128": "icons/icon.png",
      "256": "icons/icon.png",
      "512": "icons/icon.png",
      "1024": "icons/icon.png"
    }
  },
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' https://cdn.segment.com 'sha256-ZgDy59Dh4jH9g/vcPYFpoQ1wumB4IdPEOS1BJc08i+Y='; object-src 'self';"
}
```

Comment: Start with the [migration guide](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/intro/mv3-migration/).

Comment: I already updated the manifest file as much as I can with migration guide. I can't load it.  I'm getting error like this. `
Could not load background script 'js/background.js'.
Could not load manifest.`

Comment: It means there's a problem in background.js. Note that service workers don't have access to DOM, window, document, XMLHttpRequest, jQuery, $.

Comment: Right. so I want a solution how to fix it. I have forked the liquality wallet (https://github.com/liquality/wallet). I'm not sure how to update the background.js for manifest version 3.

Comment: Well, you'll need to debug it. You can do it by starting with an empty background script, then open devtools for the service worker, go to devtools `Snippets`, create a new snippet, paste the entire script, run it to see the error.

Comment: There is no error with an empty background script. But when I tried with entire script, I always have this error. `Service worker registration failed. Uncaught ReferenceError: window is not defined`. Please check this script (https://github.com/liquality/wallet/blob/release-candidate-0.66.0/src/background.js).
The error is related to the CSP of manifest version 3. I want to know how to fix this error.

Comment: The idea I suggested in my previous comment is different. Also like I already said there's no `window` in a service worker, so you'll have to rewrite your extension or use a different package.

Comment: I tried to fix it by modifying some packages, but it's still not working on my side. 
These are what I tried.

Comment: https://github.com/rubenspgcavalcante/webpack-extension-reloader/issues/125
https://github.com/rubenspgcavalcante/webpack-extension-reloader/issues/125
These are very similar. I tried all steps but it's not working now. I'm not sure. if you can have a time more for me, please take a look. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Please use the instruction (devtools snippet) in my comment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245769/discussion-between-guowang-and-woxxom).